# Why functions-framework are triggered twice when only once visited by a browser?

Tags: node.js, functions-framework

I installed `functions-framework` and run a server locally by following this document.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework

### package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "functions-framework --target=helloWorld"
  }
```

### index.js

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World');
};
```

-

```
npm start
...
Serving function...
Function: helloWorld
URL: http://localhost:8080/
curl localhost:8080
# Output: Hello, World
```

It works fine, so I changed `index.js` to use `Puppeteer`.

#### index.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.goto('https://www.google.co.jp');
}
```

When I use `curl localhost:8080`, the Chronium browser opens just once. But when I enter `localhost:8080` in browser's address bar, it opens twice.

Why the Chronium opens twice?

I checked the behavior by `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `Opera`, so it seems not depend on browsers.

Comment: I don't quite follow exactly what you're asking (probably because you aren't showing your server code), but when you type a URL in the browser bar, it often hits your server twice, once for the HTML of the page and once for the `favico.ico` for that domain that it shows in various places in the browser UI as the icon representation of the page.  `curl` does not request `favicon.ico`.

Comment: These codes are all for the localhost server. Anyway, you solved my question. I confirmed by `console.log(req.originalUrl)` that returns `/` and `favicon.ico`. Thanks!